# VB Calculate max jumps

Tags: vb.net

I am reading a .csv file in my FindMaxJumps method I am trying to make a loop to find the highest amount of jumps and set that to the highest max jumps. I have jumps set up as a String to read the csv file but thought I need to convert to a single or integer to make the comparison for all the users:

complete code:

```
   Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Button1.Click
        'Variables for each user
        Dim entryID(11) As String
        Dim location(11) As String
        Dim forename(11) As String
        Dim surname(11) As String
        Dim jumps(11) As String
        Dim bibValues(11) As String
        Dim maxJumps As Single
        Dim jumpsCounter As Single

        Call LoadAthletes(entryID, location, forename, surname, jumps)
        Call CreateBibValues(bibValues, forename, surname, location)
        Call FindMaxJumps(jumpsCounter, maxJumps, forename, surname, jumps)

    End Sub

    'Get details from reading a file
    Private Sub LoadAthletes(ByRef entryID As String(), ByRef location As String(), ByRef forname As String(), ByRef surname As String(), ByRef jumps As String())
        Dim filename As String

        filename = "C:\Users\rk\source\repos\Scottish Jumping Jax\athletes.csv"
        FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)
        For counter = 1 To 11

            Input(1, entryID(counter))
            Input(1, location(counter))
            Input(1, forname(counter))
            Input(1, surname(counter))
            Input(1, jumps(counter))
        Next
        FileClose(1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateBibValues(ByVal bibValues As String(), ByVal forename As String(), ByVal surname As String(), ByVal location As String())

        Dim locationAscii(11) As Integer
        Dim firstCharacter(11) As String
        For counter = 1 To 11
            firstCharacter(counter) = location(counter).Substring(0, 1)
            locationAscii(counter) = Asc(location(counter))
            bibValues(counter) = firstCharacter(counter) & surname(counter) & locationAscii(counter)
        Next

        Dim savedFile As String
        savedFile = ("C:\Users\rk\source\repos\Scottish Jumping Jax\bibValues.csv")
        FileOpen(1, savedFile, OpenMode.Output)
        For counter = 1 To 11
            PrintLine(1, bibValues(counter))
        Next
        FileClose(1)

    End Sub

    Private Sub FindMaxJumps(ByVal jumpsCounter As Single, ByVal maxJumps As Single, ByVal forename As String(), ByVal surname As String(), ByVal jumps As String())




    End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: What have you tried to find the max jumps?

Comment: I am trying to set maximum jumps to the value stored in the first index of the jumps away. And then loop through the array if the current jumps is more than max jumps then set max jumps to the current number of jumps.  My problem is more with I have jumps(11) As String. When I try to use it as an Integer it gives me problems reading the .csv file

Comment: Found my problem, the CSV file had title descriptions in the first line of the array so it jumps was a string and not an integer

Answer (score 0):

the corrected code

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
'Variables for each user
Dim entryID(11) As String
Dim location(11) As String
Dim forename(11) As String
Dim surname(11) As String
Dim jumps(11) As Integer
Dim bibValues(11) As String
Dim maxJumps As Integer

```
    'Define Calls and Functions
    Call LoadAthletes(entryID, location, forename, surname, jumps)
    Call CreateBibValues(bibValues, forename, surname, location)
    Call FindMaxJumps(maxJumps, jumps)
    Call DisplayMaxJumpers(maxJumps, forename, surname, jumps)
    Call TallyAthletes()

End Sub

'Get details from reading a file
Private Sub LoadAthletes(ByRef entryID As String(), ByRef location As String(), ByRef forname As String(), ByRef surname As String(), ByRef jumps As Integer())
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\Users\rk\source\repos\Scottish Jumping Jax\athletes.csv"
    FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)
    For counter = 1 To 11
        Input(1, entryID(counter))
        Input(1, location(counter))
        Input(1, forname(counter))
        Input(1, surname(counter))
        Input(1, jumps(counter))
    Next
    FileClose(1)
End Sub
'Creates the BibValues and saves it to disk
Private Sub CreateBibValues(ByVal bibValues As String(), ByVal forename As String(), ByVal surname As String(), ByVal location As String())
    'local var to determine Ascii converstion and what character to convert
    Dim locationAscii(11) As Integer
    Dim firstCharacter(11) As String
    'Loop to assign Bib Values
    For counter = 1 To 11
        firstCharacter(counter) = forename(counter).Substring(0, 1)
        locationAscii(counter) = Asc(location(counter))
        bibValues(counter) = firstCharacter(counter) & surname(counter) & locationAscii(counter)
    Next
    'Save bibValues.csv to disk
    Dim savedFile As String
    savedFile = ("C:\Users\rk\source\repos\Scottish Jumping Jax\bibValues.csv")
    FileOpen(1, savedFile, OpenMode.Output)
    For counter = 1 To 11
        PrintLine(1, bibValues(counter))
    Next
    FileClose(1)
End Sub
'Function to find max jumps
Public Function FindMaxJumps(ByVal maxJumps As Integer, ByVal jumps As Integer())
    maxJumps = jumps(1)
    For counter = 2 To 11
        If jumps(counter) > maxJumps Then
            maxJumps = jumps(counter)
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(maxJumps)

    Return maxJumps
End Function

'Determines if current number of jumps equals max jumps and displays forename and surname
Private Sub DisplayMaxJumpers(ByVal maxJumps As Integer, ByVal forename As String(), ByVal surname As String(), ByVal jumps As Integer())


End Sub
' Displays how many finalists by location
Private Sub TallyAthletes()



End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class